# Capture "quit" from dock icon in Java App

Tags: java

On OS X (and possibly on Windows but haven't tried yet) I need to interrupt the choice to quit the application with a confirmation. Note: This is NOT the close button on a window but choosing quit from the Dock Icon and the app menu. BTW, if they are different then I need both listeners. Overriding `processWindowEvent` and setting `setDefaultCloseOperation()` doesn't seem to work.

NOTE: I found a solution for Mac and included code for Windows from the accepted answer. See below.

Comment: I guess we are talking Swing here, right?

Comment: Have you added a window listener and overrided windowClosing() in it? It should handle the close button on the window and everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned `setDefaultCloseOoperation()` I assume you are talking about `JFrame`.

Here is how you can do that.

```
this.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() 
{
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) 
    {
        int ret = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(MyJFrame.this, "Are you sure you want to quit?");
        if(ret == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {
            dispose();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm checking this as the accepted answer because it does work for Windows even though it doesn't for Mac. I have included code for both in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in case anyone else is interested in this, here's what I found that works in my situation:

EDIT UPDATE: I've tested this on both Windows 10 and OSX Yosemite and it works. I've incorporated James Wierzba's code below.

Create a SEPARATE class file for the Apple quit handler (apple libraries are not included in Windows JDK):

```
import com.apple.eawt.AppEvent;
import com.apple.eawt.Application;
import com.apple.eawt.QuitHandler;
import com.apple.eawt.QuitResponse;

public class AppleQuitHandler {
    public static void DoAppleQuit() {
        Application a = Application.getApplication();
        a.setQuitHandler(new QuitHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleQuitRequestWith(AppEvent.QuitEvent quitEvent, QuitResponse quitResponse) {
                int ret = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure");
                if (ret == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    // Go ahead and exit
                    quitResponse.performQuit();
                } else {
                    // Return to program
                    quitResponse.cancelQuit();
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Add a listener to the root JFrame conditionally (Windows quit):

```
    String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    if(OS.contains("win")) {
        myJFrame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                int ret = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure");
                if (ret == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    songFrame.dispose();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Finally add the conditional for the AppleQuitHandler():

```
    String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    if(OS.contains("mac")) {
        AppleQuitHandler.DoAppleQuit();
    }
```

You should now have a working solution for Mac and Windows to capture closing from menu's and shortcut keys.

NOTE: This is NOT thoroughly tested but I did try it on both Mac and Windows.

FYI: You will need to add the Apple libs to compile on Windows.

Comment: What GUI library is this? This isn't Swing, which I think OP is referring to.

Comment: @JamesWierzba The OP is self answering this :)

Comment: Only part way. ;) I still need a way for Windows (I think)

Comment: OP please be more specific when you ask a question. When you say Java, GUI, and Mac, you could be talking about many different libraries.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for using custom apple extensions as opposed to Swing/JavaFX/etc? It will make porting your application to any other operating system more difficult.

Comment: @JamesWierzba - Apologies: As I was looking specifically for a Mac resolution and secondarily for a Windows resolution, I didn't think that would matter as the Dock/Menu stuff in Mac is handled by it's own libraries or plist from my experience. BTW. My answer works with and without Swing. I'm using a JFrame.

Comment: Ok. You can accept your own answer if it solved the problem

Comment: That seems arrogant of me to accept my own answer ;) Says I have to wait 2 days anyway. That will hopefully give me time to get an answer for Windows. I haven't even test that part yet!

Comment: @NitrogenReaction - I couldn't make the awt solution work for Mac.